# Submit virtual pageview to google analytics server-side

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to submit a virtual pageview to track events within application, that may not be associated with user visiting a page, and therefore will not allow for execution of javascript. The project is in python on GAE.

So far, I've tried to submit a pageview via an image API via a GET request, but that does't seem to work. Here's a sample URL:

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmac=UA-<account_ID>-1&utmp=/<event>/<date>
```

Given a Google Analytics account ID and domain as the only information, how do I submit a pageview to Google Analytics from server side?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039583/how-to-trigger-google-analytics-events-from-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [this lib](http://github.com/b1tr0t/Google-Analytics-for-Mobile--python-) that sends the required request to Google Analytics to mimic a page view event.

Comment: There's a fork that caters specifically to GAE APIs https://github.com/singhj/Google-Analytics-for-Mobile--Google-App-Engine

Comment: Haven't tried this yet, but went through the code and it seems like what I need. Thanks again!

Comment: That code, particularly the fork, is a disaster. I'd recommend going back to the original PHP samples google gives out, and porting it yourself. It's only a few lines.