# Downloading log files for a particular domain

Tags: google-app-engine, logging

I run the following command to download log files

```
appcfg.py --num_days=0 request_logs myappname/ "Logs.txt"
```

I want the log files of only a particular address [www.myapp.appspot.com/xyz/abc.html]
I went through the app engine documentation but could not find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it using request_logs, you need to download the entire logs and process them on your side.

Comment: My log files are huge......I am a newbie......And do not know how to process them into meaningful format.....I am interested in finding out things such as number of unique i.p addresses and hits in a day on a particular domain

Comment: @MayankKhandelwal Sounds like you need Google Analytics

Comment: I thought of google analytic.....But I am working on a desktop software....As far as I am aware Analytics does not work for that....
I actually ping appengine's website for different events.....Can something like that be done for analytics too???

Comment: @MayankKhandelwal There are some projects that allows you to work with GA server side, [check this question for more details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039583/how-to-trigger-google-analytics-events-from-python)