# GAE Mailhandler to Google Analytics

Tags: google-app-engine, google-analytics

I'm running an app on GAE that does a number of things. One of those things is receiving an email with attachment and responding with a mail with a CSV attached to it. The category of people that use this option, never visit the site.

Would it be possible to add something to my mailhandler so that every mail received is processed as a page visit in Google Analytics?

I'm using Jinja2 as framework.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to trigger Google Analytics events from Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039583/how-to-trigger-google-analytics-events-from-python) and most likely those answers might help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Google Analytics for Mobile Websites](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/other/mobileWebsites). It allows for server-side invocation.

Basically it just produces an image url that triggers GA when loaded in mobile site. In your case you should invoke this url with your own parameters. Here is an example Url:

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=4&utmn=769876874&utmhn=example.com&utmcs=ISO-8859-1&utmsr=1280x1024&utmsc=32-bit&utmul=en-us&utmje=1&utmfl=9.0%20%20r115&utmcn=1&utmdt=GATC012%20setting%20variables&utmhid=2059107202&utmr=0&utmp=/auto/GATC012.html?utm_source=www.gatc012.org&utm_campaign=campaign+gatc012&utm_term=keywords+gatc012&utm_content=content+gatc012&utm_medium=medium+gatc012&utmac=UA-30138-1&utmcc=__utma%3D97315849.1774621898.1207701397.1207701397.1207701397.1%3B...
```

See here for a [full list of parameters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gaTrackingTroubleshooting?hl=en#gifParametershttp://).