# Combining Google Analytics client- and server side tracking

Tags: google-analytics

I track my users behavior using Google Analytics client side. At some point the user is redirected to one of my partners and I receive a callback from the partner about the value the user has generated.

The question is: How do I append that value from the callback as a goal with a value to the users session?

The objective is to be able to get insights about which of my traffic sources generate the most value (and not just most conversions - as that could be tracked with event tracking).

The solution might be similar to this one, but I'm not sure it's still the best solution - and there could be others as well.
[Using Google Analytics to track the same session in client javascript and server side tracking calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792139/using-google-analytics-to-track-the-same-session-in-client-javascript-and-server)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a similar problem.  In my case the user is redirected to a 3rd party site and then redirect back to my site.  I am finding insight such as the source and referring are getting lost (and instead take on the values of the site I redirected them too).  It is like the GA session gets dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that this is now possible with the new Universal Analytics from Google by saving/syncing the users UUID to the server and then tracking any relevant events.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-id

This package seems like a nice wrapper: https://www.npmjs.org/package/universal-analytics

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use same userId (not clientId). That works for multi-device tracking https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123662

Universal-analytics is better in that you can use it for anonymous users as well as signed-in users

But tracking by userId is better in that you can send events even if user is not currently on your website doing http or websocket requests.